# How can I get a CultureInfo or RegionInfo from United Nations M49 Country code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, regioninfo

I want to create the ISO code from the UN M49 code which I receive from database. How can I do that in c#?

ex: Sweden's UN M49 code is 752. How can I convert it to something like Sweden or Iso code "sv"

I try to create CultureInfo and RegionInfo from that code but C# doesn't regconize it.

Comment: I doubt anyone knows what `UN M49` is. The standards organization everyone knows and uses is ISO. The CultureInfo and RegionInfo aren't databases of all possible code and country representations either. They're specifically used for localization and contain only information relevant to this scenario.